# How to write junit for static class of methods using mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can I mock and expect in JUnit for the following code?

```
esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper(Mockito.anyString(), "Somethin", "Something")
```

my full example class:

```
    import esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper;//external library
Class Common {

public static String getUserId(HttpServletRequest request){

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String test = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie thisCookie = cookies[i];
            String cookieName = thisCookie.getName();

            if ("test".equals(cookieName)) {
                test = thisCookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }

        String encrypted = esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper(test, "CSP", "PROD");///unable to mock this in mockito framework
        String userId = encrypted.split("\\|")[5];
        return userId;
    }
}
```

till for loop its working while doing junit. after that i couldnt mock for the statement .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: what you showed IS a mock. Can you clarify what you are struggling with?

Comment: am struggling to mock a statement in mockito esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper(Mockito.anyString(), "Somethin", "Something")

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper(Mockito.anyString(), "Somethin", "Something").thenReturn("Some Value");`?

Comment: Yes.esGateKeeper is static class. so i am getting error when mocking

Comment: @Sri there exist no `static` classes in java, what type of class are you talking about?

Comment: esGateKeeper - this is external library which is static. so i want to make this statement (esGateKeeper.esGateKeeper(Mockito.anyString(), "Somethin", "Something").thenReturn("Some Value");)as mock.

Comment: @Sri there also exists no such thing as *static library* can you please clarify what you mean with `static`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176862/discussion-between-sri-and-lino).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMockito in conjunction with JUnit for this, here is an example

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassWithStaticMethod.class})
public class SomeStaticMethodTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStaticMethod.class);
        when(ClassWithStaticMethod.getInstance()).thenReturn(new MockClassWithStaticMethod()); // getInstance() is a static method
        //some test condition
    }    
}
```

[More information information here.](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method)

Cheers!